# Store Model Evaluation Metrics to Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

currently I'm working in the setup of Sagemaker as our team ML Ops platform and we would like to store model evaluation metrics together with the model itself.

Now we are creating the model using the boto3 sagemaker client:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_model

But I don't see how to attach metrics to it, so we could run the model evaluation and store the metrics to keep track of them.

The goal is to have the model in Sagemaker so we can deploy it as an endpoint.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach metrics to the model if you register it in the Model Registry using the `create_model_package` API. There is an argument called `ModelMetrics` in the API that you can use for this. The metrics must be stored in a file in S3 and you will provide the S3 URI in this API call.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateModelPackage.html

Comment: i am saving the metrics on S3 and registering the model on sagemaker model registry. But i don't know why the metrics are not being loaded on the sagemaker studios. Is there any set format that metric file in S3 should adhere to?